# mDNS for chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Will support for mDNS api for Chrome Extensions be added? Is there any way to get information on the timeline (or exclusion) of this feature? Chrome has an mDNS api for Chrome apps but not for extensions, it would be very helpful for my product if users didn't have to install a native electron app just to do discovery of our IOT-like devices seeing as chrome-apps are being discontinued for Windows and OSX.

Comment: FYI: mDNS for extensions is currently implemented privately for the Cast button.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I think I saw that in some Chromium source some place. Seems like a silly thing to keep to yourself. I'll file a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also checked the documentation and it seems that [mDNS](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/mdns) is still not yet supported in extensions. I suggest to file a [feature request](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/faq#faq-fea-02) for this.

> If you identify a feature (especially if it's related to an experimental API) that could be added to improve the extension development experience, make sure an appropriate request is filed in the issue tracker.

Feature request: [804945](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=804945)

Comment: I've created feature request [804945](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=804945) for this. Using the new issue wizard I didn't seam to be able to set the type to feature request or the component to Platform>Extensions. 

Maybe you know someone that can help correct those labels so this doesn't get round-binned? Thanks for the help @abielita